# Button savedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, onsaveinstancestate

Saving the State of Drawable xml Button.

```
private boolean mJam;
private button mSwitch;
private static final String     KEY_ENABLE          = "KEY_ENABLE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if( null == savedInstanceState ) {
        mJam = false; 
    } else {
        mJam = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_ENABLE);
    }
   button_layout();

  }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_ENABLE,  mJam);
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_ENABLE, mSwitch.isSelected()); // Saving the state of the
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSwitch.setSelected(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_ENABLE));
    mJam = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_ENABLE);
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Note: If you don't want to use ScreenSize in Android manifest, This code can be used,
If you want to do it Manually, then go for this one.
P.S: setting Screen Size in Manifest, never go to onCreate if the Orientation Change, It Just saved all the instance and display as it is, when
Android orientation Change.

Comment: Why do you `putBoolean` with the same key `KEY_ENABLE` twice in `onSaveInstanceState`?

Comment: You should use different keys for different inputs. Putting them the same like that will create bugs